# Offset of button not animated using an ExpressionAnimation

Tags: uwp, composition

Currently, I'm experimenting a bit with the `Windows.UI.Composition` namespace.

```
var offsetAnimation = compositor.CreateExpressionAnimation();
offsetAnimation.SetReferenceParameter("ps", _propertySet);
offsetAnimation.Expression = "ps.myValue";

var buttonVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(testButton);
buttonVisual .StartAnimation("Offset.X", offsetAnimation);
```

The `_propertySet` is specific for the page, `myValue` is added/updated from another method.

The code of the button:

```
<Button x:Name="testButton" Background="Red" />
```

The problem is that the `Offset` of the button doesn't change, instead nothing happens. However when I'm animating either the `Opacity` or the `Scale` property, the same expression is working. I've added a `WebView` to my page as well, here the `Offset` is animated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Offset is of type **System.Numerics.Vector3**. An easier way to animate would be by using the **Vector3KeyFrameAnimation**.

```
var newOffset = new Vector3(newValueX, newValueY, newValuez);
var offsetAnimation = compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
offsetAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
offsetAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1f, newOffset);

var buttonVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(testButton);
buttonVisual .StartAnimation("Offset", offsetAnimation);
```

Comment: A *KeyFrameAnimation* is no solution, as `myValue` is based on user input.

Comment: Based on the user input you can create the **newOffset** object. Create your offsetAnimation and cache it. Once you create the **newOffset** you can set the keyframe by calling `offsetAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1f, newOffset);`

Answer (score 0):

Variable `_propertySet` should be derived from `CompositionObject` class if you use `ExpressionAnimation.SetReferenceParameter`. You can set `_anotherVisual.Offset.X` but you can't just set some float field.

If you wish to animate visual offset to some value - implement implicit animation.